# Filter on xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have one XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<File>
    <Cars>
        <Car>
            <Color>Blue</Color>
            <Year>1988</Year>
        </Car>
        <Car>
            <Color>Green</Color>
            <Year>1989</Year>
        </Car>
        <Car>
            <Color>Yellow</Color>
            <Year>1989</Year>
        </Car>
    </Cars>
</File>
```

I want to create a filter on this file with this object :

```
public class condition
{
    public string color { get; set; }

    public string year { get; set; }
}

List<condition> c = new List<condition>
{
    new condition()
    {
        color = "Green",
        year = "1989"
    },
    new condition()
    {
        color = "Blue",
        year = "1988"
    }
};
```

I want to take only car with `(color = Green and year = 1989) OR (color = blue and year = 1988)`

But I don't have idea how to do this. Maybe with XDocument and Linq.Dynamic ?

Comment: I would serialize the XML into a list of Car objects, and then use LINQ to perform list comprehensions comparing the Car objects to your condition objects.

Comment: Do you mean populating specific content from xml file to your object

Comment: I want to remove all item that doesn't not fit under the conditions. @SonnyChilds is it possible without serialize ? I would avoid creating correspondence class

Answer (score 1):

You can easily filter xml in linq using a`XDocument`. This function will remove all nodes based on a filter using the `Remove()` extension method.

```
private void RemoveCars(string color, string year)
{
  var doc = XDocument.Load("<myxml>...</myxml>");
  doc.Element("File")
     .Element("Cars")
     .Elements("Cars")
     .Where(c=> c.Element("color").Value == color
                && c.Element("Year").Value == year)
     .Remove();

  doc.Save("c:\\mypath\\my.xml");

}
```

Comment: Thanks ! How to save file with the changes then ?

Comment: do a google search on how to save changes to xml file.. don't rely on everyone to do the simple stuff for you.

Comment: see updated answer.. and please make sure you understand what you're doing, as well.

Comment: I want to keep element, not remove

Comment: the code above can be easily changed to do that. Can you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Another Option you can use Linq to xml

```
  //XElement xFile = XElement.Load("D:/Sample.xml");
        XElement xFile = XElement.Parse
            (@"<File>
                  <Cars>
                    <Car>
                      <Color>Blue</Color>
                      <Year>1988</Year>
                    </Car>
                    <Car>
                      <Color>Green</Color>
                      <Year>1989</Year>
                    </Car>
                    <Car>
                      <Color>Yellow</Color>
                      <Year>1989</Year>
                    </Car>
                  </Cars>
                </File> ");
        List<condition> c = new List<condition>
                        {
                            new condition()
                            {
                                color = "Green",
                                year = "1989"
                            },
                            new condition()
                            {
                                color = "Blue",
                                year = "1988"
                            }
                        };
        var s = new XElement("Cars",
                from cc in c
                select new XElement("Car",
                    new XElement("Color", cc.color),
                    new XElement("Year", cc.year)
                )   

                );  
        var result = xFile.Descendants("Cars").Intersect(s.Descendants("Cars"));

        var fileXML = new XElement("File", result);
        fileXML.Save("D:/Result.xml");
```